# bootstrap window management framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, kibana

Is anyone aware of an (angularjs / bootstrap based preferably) window management framework. I'm looking like something similar to what elasticsearch is using for their kibana dashboards.

[image]

The concepts Im looking for is responsive, panels with mixed content, rows/columns with panels, user can change layout (change size, drag drop panels around) etc.

Thanks!

Sander

Comment: yes I am aware...so you are hiring me for this work?;)

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava You are a funny one :-)

Comment: found it... gridster, the same that the kibana guys are using